# How to redirect user to 'view' without going through smartgrid in web2py

Tags: python, model-view-controller, web2py

how do i redirect a registered user to his/her db.table.id 'view' without going through smartgrid in web2py?

i have tried using:

`redirect(URL(f='first', args=['mydata/view', 'mydata/%s', %request.vars.name]))`

where `mydata` is the view for my table `db.mydata` and 'first' is my function.
It always returns to the smartgrid interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. First, the final URL argument must be the record ID, but it looks like you are instead using a name (i.e., `request.vars.name`). Second, by default, the grid uses signed URLs, so you must either disable the signatures (not recommended) or add a user signature to the URL you generate. So, the link should be something like this:

```
redirect(URL(f='first', args=['mydata', 'view', 'mydata', request.vars.id],
             user_signature=True))
```

Also, note that in the `args` list, each element can (and generally should) be a separate URL arg. So, instead of `['mydata/view', ...]`, it should be `['mydata', 'view', ...]`.

Comment: It worked like magic. I just edited the request.vars.id to my SQLFORM name, that is, form.vars.id.....thanks a lot!